# Get label text inside listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview with 2 labels inside and 1 label (lbl1) outside the listview.
I want to make lbl1 text = the label inside the listview.

kindly answer in full details, I'm a noob.
whenever I run the below code I get this error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label mylabel = (Label)ListView1.FindControl("prog_idLabel");
    lbl1.Text = mylabel.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
    Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindControl("prog_idLabel");
    lblID.Text = mylabel.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly some defensive programming wouldn't go amiss to stop your application crashing.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label mylabel = (Label)ListView1.FindControl("prog_idLabel");
    if(mylabel != null)
         lbl1.Text = mylabel.Text;
}
```

That way if FindControl returns null, or your casting doesn't work you won't be accessing a null object.

I think that page_load is getting called before you instantiate the label inside the listview.
So consider putting your code elsewhere, where you can be sure that everything has been initialised.

Comment: I dont get the error anymore but i dont see the lbl1 with the updated text.

Comment: This is probably due to what I said in the last paragraph. The chances are that Page_Load is getting called before prog_idlabel is created and added to the listview. I don't know how your code is structured but maybe put the code in Page_Load after InitializeComponent(); in your class constructor

Comment: Created a test page and inserted the code in a button. after the page loads, the listview have the information, when I click the button to run the code... I get nothing, what to do now?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first line of your code. Then have a look inside the listviews controls and see if your label is there. The reason it is not working I think is that it can't find prog_idlabel and is returning null. Where exactly are you adding this label to the listview?

Comment: Where are you adding the label to the listview? Look inside ListView1.Controls and see if your label is there

Comment: do me a favor please, create a listview with label and try to copy that label text to a label outside the list, thank you for your support.

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="data_trackerDS">
            
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="prog_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("prog_name") %>' /></td>
<td><asp:Label ID="prog_idLabel" runat="server" Text='  <%# Eval("prog_id") %>' Visible = "true" style="color: #FFCC00"/></td>
                      
                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>       
                        
            </asp:ListView>

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your controls are all set to an instance of an object first. It looks like this is not the case. You're working on an ASP.NET project right ? If so, it looks like [your event handler is this one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/page-load). You have to make sure this is the right one to use, maybe you were looking for another event.

To verify that all instances are set properly, set a break point when you instantiate the control that returns the null reference. If you get your exception before you hit the break point, you should understant what is happening. Run your code slowly step by step.

Comment: what is the event handler of listview?